# Getting data from another website using C# and displaying in a web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, web-part, csom, c-sharp

I'm trying to read information sitting in another wesbsite using C# and displaying the result in sharepoint 2010 web part. I read about httprequest but I'm failing to implement it. Please anyone help with simplest solution you can give.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537247(v%3Doffice.14)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via the `Client Side Object Model`, by referencing the below DLL's to your solution

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime

> The above DLL's located at `C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\`

**CSOM C# Code**

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("your list");

    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
    context.Load(list);
    context.Load(listItems);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

   // Load your data t gridview
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   table.Columns.Add("Title");
   foreach (ListItem item in items)
     table.Rows.Add( item["Title"]);
   Gridview.DataSource = table;
}
```

> **Note:** it's important to set the `NetworkCredential` parameters correctly, also you can add this info in the web config, then read it
>   from there!